# send ResultSet data from jsp to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a button, onclick event of this button I am calling a ajax function which is including the content of a jsp page into a DIV. On JSP page I am making a query to database and getting the data in ResultSet, this data I want to show in a table and graph on same JSP page, Table I can create directly in same page, but How to pass the data into java script to plot a Graph. This is my ajax function :

```
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: symbol,
      success: function(data) {
          //data contain content of JSP page which also contain ResultSet and also a div element in which i want to show graph
          var content =data;
          //this is adding content into a div element.
            $('#tt').tabs('add',{
                title:title,
                content:content,
                closable:true
            });
    //here i am looking to write the code for plotting graph.
            var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);

      },
      error: function(e) {
          alert("error : "+e);
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From resultset you create Json and eval it in your jsp.
so this way your data will available in jsp